# Error when adding Tabpages in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am having issues with adding tab pages to a tab control. I am using visual studio 2012. When I execute the code below i get the four tab pages with the following captions - Index 4, Index 2, Index 3, Index 4. as my four tabs. I loose the frist tab that should be "index 1" and tab 4 is repeated as the first tab. Below is the code.

```
    for Index = 0 to 3
        ItemName = "Index " + Convert.ToString(Index)
        tabPage.Text = ItemName
        frmConsole.tbcMain.TabPages.Add(tabPage)
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a new `TabPage` with each iteration.

```
For Index = 1 to 4
    Dim tabPage As New TabPage
    tabPage.Text = "Index " & Index.ToString
    frmConsole.tbcMain.TabPages.Add(tabPage)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew I couldn't have been much.